# Wp_Mail: Unable to Send Email using Gmail SMTP Because of Less Secure App Access No Longer Available

Tags: php, wordpress, gmail, phpmailer

Wordpress Developer.

As we know, Google no longer supports Less Secure App Access at 30 May 2022.
Link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

I'm already did two step verification, and also make app password. But that still not working. I cannot send the automated email through localhost. Long time ago, I can make register form verification, but after that sending email using wp_mail() not working anymore.

This is my code smtp email setting:

```
//SMTP email settings
define( 'SMTP_USER', 'hendratrisno08@gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_FROM', 'hendratrisno08@gmail.com' );
define( 'SMTP_NAME', 'Hendra Sutrisno' );
define( 'SMTP_PORT', '587' );
define( 'SMTP_SECURE', 'TLS' );
define( 'SMTP_AUTH', true );
```

And then this is my sendEmail function:

```
static function _sendEmail(){

        $sendto = "sutrisnohendra08@gmail.com";
        
        $sendfrom = 'hendratrisno08@gmail.com';
        $headers = array("Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8","From: Me Myself <". $sendfrom . ">");
   
        $sendsub = 'Thank you for Subscribe!';
        $sendmess = 'Hello, Thank You!';
      
               
        wp_mail($sendto, $sendsub, $sendmess, $headers);

    }
```

I don't know whether my code that not working, or from gmail / Google side. All answer is much appreciated, Thank You!

Best Regards,

Hendra

Comment: please edit your question and include the error you are getting after setting the apps password in your code.   "Not working" does not properly describe the issue

Comment: When I test gmass.co/smtp-test, the error is like this: ERROR: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Comment: I want to ask, the SMTP_PASS is the account password or app password?

Comment: That error message is not related to your password.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60665133/1841839